# How to call a simple web service from IONIC

Tags: javascript, web-services, ionic-framework

Am working with IONIC were am trying to call a simple login webservice,But unable to pass the required header and body parameters of the service from IONIC code.

curl request of the webservice:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "ModifiedOn:0" -H "username:vikash|214057357158656" -H "password:gbadmin" -d '{"username":"vikash|214057357158656","password":"gbadmin"}' http://localhost:8282/services/Login3.0
```

Response:

```
{"ResponseJSON":{"Body":{"Datalist":{"Authentication":"true"}}}}
```

My IONIC Code:

```
$scope.login = function() {
 $http.post("http://redmine.youtility.in:8282/services/Login3.0", {"username":"vikash|214057357158656","password":"gbadmin"},"Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "ModifiedOn:0" -H "username:vikash|214057357158656" -H "password:gbadmin");
```

how to pass the parameters in the IONIC code and get response from the web service.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this, here i have given a sample post method for you requirement.

```
    var userDetails = {
                        "username":"vikash|214057357158656",
                        "password":"gbadmin"
                       }
    $scope.login = function() {
     $http.post("http://redmine.youtility.in:8282/services/Login3.0",userDetails)
    .success (function(response){
        console.log(response);
     }
     .error(function(response){
        console.log(response);
     };
    }
```

For more details take a look this angular website for [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) .